# Dynamic invocation of handler functions in C++

Tags: c++, web-applications, dispatcher

I am trying to understand a particular web architecture.
There is a cgi web application which works this way.

The request from web browser comes to the apache web server which is then routed to an application dispatcher.

Application dispatcher has a config file which has all the possibles commands and its corresponding handler methods.

Say, if there is a `cmd=_login` request from the browser, dispatcher looks for config file which may have this entry.

> Command: _login
>
> Handler: handle_login()
>
> Header: login.h
>
> Binary: Exe_name

So, what are the ways by which, application dispatcher can fork the cgi binary (Exe_name) and directly invoke `handle_login()` function?

Can a particular method be directly invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two approaches to doing symbol resolution.

#### Built-in symbol resolution.

Depending on your system, you may be able to look up regular functions by name in a hidden symbol table used at run-time.  For example, the [`dlopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) and [`dlsym()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) on UNIX-like systems allow you to load a shared object library and resolve functions in that library by name.  Windows has similarly behaving functions [`LoadLibrary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetProcAddress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for dynamically linked libraries (DLLs).  You have to pay attention to the concept of *visibility*.  Functions must be *exported* by the library in order to be resolved using this mechanism.  I believe GCC creates exports all functions by default (visibility is public) and Windows compilers export nothing by default.  Also note that on Windows, you can resolve functions in the host program without loading an external library because the null library handle designates the host process's executable image.

In general, this is full of subtleties and not portable.  I don't recomment you build a system based on this mechanism.

#### Manual symbol resolution: routes

The modern way of mapping URLs (or parts of URLs) to  functions is to build URL *routes*.  This approached is adopted by most modern web frameworks based on the MVC paradigm (Ruby on Rails, Django and ASP.NET MVC to name a few -- there are many others).

This basically consists in building a map of names (or regular expressions) to callbacks (in C++, this would be a pointer to function or a `std::function<>` object).  If your compiler supports the up and coming standard, you should be able to populate a `std::map< std::regex,std::function<void()>>` object to implement the look-up.

Here is a simple (untested) example:

```
// GET request for login.
void handle_login_page ()
{
     // CGI handler: read from `std::cin` and write to `std::cout`...
}

// POST request for login.
void handle_login_form ()
{
     // CGI handler: read from `std::cin` and write to `std::cout`...
}

typedef std::function<void()> Handler;
typedef std::map<std::string, Handler> Routes;

void handle_request ( const Routes& routes, const std::string& command )
{
     // locate handler.
     Routes::const_iterator match = routes.find(command);
     if (match == routes.end()) {
         // exit with 404 status.
     }
     const Handler handler = match->second;

     // log access or other pre-processing.
     // ...

     // invoke handler.
     handler();
}

int main ()
{
    Routes routes;
    routes["get_login"] = &handle_login_page;
    routes["post_login"] = &handle_login_form;
    // ...

    // accept a connection.
    // fork.
    // get command name.
    const std::string command = ...;
    handle_request(routes, command);
}
```

Comment: The second method was what I was looking for. Let me now take a look at function pointers.

Comment: Is there any need that all the handler functions should take same parameter?

Comment: Yes, all handlers  must have the same signature, or they cannot be kept in the same container.  If you want to special case a few of them, you will have to add a manual dispatch, such as (`if(command=="special-case"){handle_special_case(foo,bar);}else{handle_request(routes,command);}`

Answer (score 0):

You're not really clear whether you're using Windows or Linux, but the ability to load modules and execute a given function within them is pretty standard functionality for modules.

Here are two related/helpful functions from the Win32 API:

[`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Take a look at [`dlopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) and [`dlsym`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) in that case, I believe those are what you're looking for.